# How to set PATH that will be used via ssh

Tags: ssh, setup

Using ssh between 2 Pi's, I need to alter the path that is seen within ssh.
If I read the path locally I see

```
pi@pi-test:~ $ echo $PATH
/home/pi/.guix-profile/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
pi@pi-test:~ $
```

however if I look via ssh from another Pi I see

```
pi@pi4b:~ $ ssh pi@pi-test-wifi 'echo $PATH'
pi@pi-test-wifi's password: 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
pi@pi4b:~ $
```

How can I see the path which is seen inside ssh?  I have done some research but the solutions I have found are old and the option files referred to don't seem to exist anymore.
Thanks
Mick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is answered in this [Q&A on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332532/how-to-set-path-when-running-a-ssh-command). Briefly:

1. on the "server" host (`pi-test-wifi` *I believe*) - edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as follows:

   **FROM:** `# PermitUserEnvironment no`

   **TO:** `PermitUserEnvironment yes`
2. on the "server" host, create or modify the file `~/.ssh/environment`, and **add the following line**:

   `PATH=/home/pi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

   Alternatively, set the PATH to whatever you wish, however you wish - as long as you do it in this file.
3. Reboot, or `sudo service ssh restart`

This worked for me:

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi3b:~ $ ssh pi@raspberrypi4b.local 'echo $PATH'
pi@raspberrypi4b.local's password:
/home/pi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
pi@raspberrypi3b:~ $
```

Comment: Brilliant!!  Thank you, I have been trying to fix this for several days no.

Comment: @MickSulley: Glad it helped. It took me a few minutes to grasp what you were trying to do 'cause my typical MO is using SSH to access an interactive shell. Using it the way you've described will be very useful at times - so I learned something as well!

Answer (score 0):

The PATH will be the same as the user.

`ssh pi@pi-test-wifi 'echo $PATH'` doesn't do what you think.

If you ssh into the Pi THEN list the PATH you will get the true value.

NOTE Your question is confused pi-test-wifi is NOT pi-test

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my device naming is a bit unorthodox. I need to run unison across machines and it needs to see the correct path in the remote machine, so I need to change the path which is seen in the example, and I cannot figure out how to do it.